# Failure of "equivariant triangulation" for finite complexes equipped with a $G$-action

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, equivariant-homotopy

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the $\infty$-category of spaces, and let $G$ be a finite group, and let $BG$ be the groupoid with one object and automorphisms given by $G$. 
Consider the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Fun}(BG, \mathcal{S})$. (Note: This can be presented via a model category of $G$-spaces where the weak equivalences are the *nonequivariant* homotopy equivalences. In particular, this should not be confused with the category of $G$-equivariant spaces.) Some natural examples of objects in this $\infty$-category include the orbits $G/H$ for $H \subset G$ a subgroup (regarded as discrete spaces). Say that an object in this $\infty$-category is **$G$-finite** if it belongs to the smallest subcategory of $\mathrm{Fun}(BG, \mathcal{S})$ generated by finite colimits and retracts by the orbits $\{G/H\}$ for $H \subset G$. In other words, the object can be represented by a retract of a finite $G$-CW complex.

If an object of $\mathrm{Fun}(BG, \mathcal{S})$ is $G$-finite, then clearly the underlying space is a retract of a finite CW complex. I'd like to know if the converse is true. That is, is there a simple example of an object of this category (i.e., a space with a $G$-action) whose underlying space is finitely dominated (i.e., compact in $\mathcal{S}$) but which does not lie in the subcategory generated under finite colimits and retracts by the $\{G/H\}_{H \subset G}$?

It is also possible to ask the same question for the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Sp}$ replacing $\mathcal{S}$: that is, one considers $\mathrm{Fun}(BG, \mathrm{Sp})$ and the unreduced suspension spectra of orbits, $\Sigma^\infty_+ (G/H)$, for $H \subset G$. These generate a thick subcategory of $\mathrm{Fun}(BG, \mathrm{Sp})$ which is contained in the subcategory $\mathrm{Fun}(BG, \mathrm{Sp}^\omega)$ spanned by those objects in 
$\mathrm{Fun}(BG, \mathrm{Sp})$ whose underlying spectrum is finite (if we write $\mathrm{Sp}^\omega$ for the $\infty$-category of finite spectra). Are these subcategories the same? That is, is $\mathrm{Fun}(BG, \mathrm{Sp}^\omega)$ generated as a thick subcategory by the $(G/H)_+$?

**Remark:** Suppose $X \in \mathrm{Fun}(B\mathbb{Z}/p, \mathrm{Sp}^\omega)$. Then, if $X$ belongs to the thick subcategory generated by the orbits, the $p$-completion of the Tate construction $X^{t \mathbb{Z}/p}$ will be the $p$-completion of a finite spectrum by the Segal conjecture. I'm curious if it is possible to construct an object $X$ as above such that $X^{t \mathbb{Z}/p}$ does not satisfy this.
That would give a negative answer to the second question.

Comment: In Fun(BG,S), the orbits G/H generally won't be compact when H is nontrivial. But G itself generates the compact objects under finite colimits and retracts (this follows formally from the fact that it is a compact object which corepresents a conservative functor: in this case, the functor which forgets the G-action).

Comment: @JacobLurie: I agree, but I'm looking for objects in $\mathrm{Fun}(BG, \mathcal{S})$ whose image in $\mathcal{S}$ is compact; they don't have to be compact in $\mathrm{Fun}(BG, \mathcal{S})$ itself.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood you. I don't have very much helpful to suggest, then. One comment: in the special case G = Z/p,  if a space X with an action of G is to have the form you describe, then it satisfies the Sullivan conjecture. In particular, the homotopy fixed points for the action of G on the p-adic completion X_p must itself arise as the p-adic completion of a finite space. Possibly this could give you a way to test if something is a counterexample? (A finite X w/G action such that (X_p)^hG is not the p-adic completion of anything finite?)

Comment: @Jacob: Yes, that's precisely the kind of reasoning that I had hoped would be applicable. I'm also interested in the case of finite group actions on finite spectra (in which case one could hope to use the Segal conjecture). Still, it doesn't seem easy to build a natural example (especially since one would need to be able to say something about the homotopy fixed points for this).

Comment: Actually wait: I've misunderstood the question again, and what I said doesn't necessarily apply. (It applies when X comes from a finite object in the "genuine" equivariant category. But your finiteness condition looks like it might be weaker than that, even without allowing retracts.)

Comment: For $\mathbb{Z}/p$-actions on finite spectra, then if a spectrum $X \in \mathrm{Fun}(B\mathbb{Z}/p, \mathrm{Sp})$ belongs to the thick subcategory generated by $S^0$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/p)_+$, its Tate construction needs to be the $p$-adic completion of a finite spectrum. I was hoping that it might be possible to argue along those lines.

Comment: I'm not sure if this comment will be helpful or not, but you might consider checking out section 9.4 of Hovey-Palmieri-Strickland Axiomatic Stable Homotopy Theory. What you're asking about seems related to Theorem 9.4.3 and the discussion after. I seem to recall that when G/H fails to embed into the universe in question that things can break badly. I know G/H can fail to be strongly dualizable for instance. But I don't know how to build the example you're looking for.